# CSS- / SVG-animation : Why isn't the hover-state triggered immediately?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have made this animated icon with CSS and SVG:

```css
.twitter-outline {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #4099ff;
}

.twitter-icon {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: transparent; 
}

.twitter-outline, .twitter-icon {
 transition: 600ms all;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.twitter-icon-group:hover .twitter-outline {
 transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0;
}

.twitter-icon-group:hover .twitter-icon {
 transform: scale(2);
 fill: #4099ff;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <g class="twitter-icon-group">
              <circle class="twitter-outline" cx="110.6" cy="100.5" r="35.2"/>

              <path fill="#4099ff" d="M125.4 91.8c-1 .5-2.3 1-3.5 1 1-.8 2-2 2-3.4-1 .7-2.6 1.2-4 1.5-1-2-2.6-2-4.4-2-3.3 0-6 2-6 6v1c-5-.6-9.4-3-12.4-6.7-.6 1-1 2-1 3 0 2 1.2 4 2.8 5-1 0-2-.2-2.6-.7 0 3 2 5.4 5 6l-1.8.2h-1c.6 2.2 3 4 5.5 4-2 1.6-4.6 2.6-7.5 2.6h-1c2.4 1.5 5.5 2.5 9 2.5 11 0 17.2-9.3 17.2-17.3 1.2-1 2.2-2 3-3.2z"/>

              <path class="twitter-icon" d="M125.4 91.8c-1 .5-2.3 1-3.5 1 1-.8 2-2 2-3.4-1 .7-2.6 1.2-4 1.5-1-2-2.6-2-4.4-2-3.3 0-6 2-6 6v1c-5-.6-9.4-3-12.4-6.7-.6 1-1 2-1 3 0 2 1.2 4 2.8 5-1 0-2-.2-2.6-.7 0 3 2 5.4 5 6l-1.8.2h-1c.6 2.2 3 4 5.5 4-2 1.6-4.6 2.6-7.5 2.6h-1c2.4 1.5 5.5 2.5 9 2.5 11 0 17.2-9.3 17.2-17.3 1.2-1 2.2-2 3-3.2z"/>
        </g>          
</svg>
```

If one hovers with the mouse point over the icon then the outer circle shall vanish.

It works. But one has to reach far into the circle with the mouse pointer. When one reaches the bird (almost) **then** the animation is triggered.

I would expect it to be triggered immediately after the circle is hovered.

Because that's what my code says: " *.**twitter-icon-group:hover** .twitter-outline {* "

**What goes wrong here?** I have already tried to remove padding on the SVG group. But that haven't work.

**How can get it to trigger the hover-state when then circle it hovered?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `circle` has no `fill` and so only the actual 'path' can be hovered.

Just change that `fill` to `transparent`.

*EDIT: As pointed out by @RobertLongson we should be using `pointer-events:fill` rather than `fill:transparent`.*

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MjNXrr)

[**Pointer-Events @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> **fill**
>
> SVG only. The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the pointer is over the interior (i.e., fill) of the element. The values of the fill and visibility properties do not affect event processing

```css
.twitter-outline {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: fill;
  stroke: #4099ff;
}
.twitter-icon {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: transparent;
}
.twitter-outline,
.twitter-icon {
  transition: 600ms all;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.twitter-icon-group:hover .twitter-outline {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.twitter-icon-group:hover .twitter-icon {
  transform: scale(2);
  fill: #4099ff;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <g class="twitter-icon-group">
    <circle class="twitter-outline" cx="110.6" cy="100.5" r="35.2" />

    <path fill="#4099ff" d="M125.4 91.8c-1 .5-2.3 1-3.5 1 1-.8 2-2 2-3.4-1 .7-2.6 1.2-4 1.5-1-2-2.6-2-4.4-2-3.3 0-6 2-6 6v1c-5-.6-9.4-3-12.4-6.7-.6 1-1 2-1 3 0 2 1.2 4 2.8 5-1 0-2-.2-2.6-.7 0 3 2 5.4 5 6l-1.8.2h-1c.6 2.2 3 4 5.5 4-2 1.6-4.6 2.6-7.5 2.6h-1c2.4 1.5 5.5 2.5 9 2.5 11 0 17.2-9.3 17.2-17.3 1.2-1 2.2-2 3-3.2z"
    />

    <path class="twitter-icon" d="M125.4 91.8c-1 .5-2.3 1-3.5 1 1-.8 2-2 2-3.4-1 .7-2.6 1.2-4 1.5-1-2-2.6-2-4.4-2-3.3 0-6 2-6 6v1c-5-.6-9.4-3-12.4-6.7-.6 1-1 2-1 3 0 2 1.2 4 2.8 5-1 0-2-.2-2.6-.7 0 3 2 5.4 5 6l-1.8.2h-1c.6 2.2 3 4 5.5 4-2 1.6-4.6 2.6-7.5 2.6h-1c2.4 1.5 5.5 2.5 9 2.5 11 0 17.2-9.3 17.2-17.3 1.2-1 2.2-2 3-3.2z"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: "Just change that fill to transparent." Indeed ! Works like charm. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I always forget that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the circle being only 1px wide. When you hover the actual circle path, and not the space between the icon and the path, it's in hover state.